# Is it better to write methods that return a value or operate on the data directly?

Tags: angular, typescript

When writing a class in typescript (or even javascript) is it better to write methods that return a value or to operate on the data directly?  In the end, I need the value of the original variable changed.

```
let x: number = 4;

addFive(myInput: number): number {
  return myInput + 5;
}

addSix(): void {
  this.x += 6;
}

console.log(x);  // 4

x = addFive(x);
console.log(x);  // 9

addSix(x);
console.log(x);  // 15
```

This is a very simple example and the actual methods that I'm writing are specific to the original data and cannot be reused generally.

For unit testing purposes, I see the advantage of returning value, but sometimes it just seems like overkill.

Comment: **Pure Functions**

Comment: It's totally fine to change data directly if its meant to be changed, so second function is better choice, if you want to keep original and get new value then using first one would be right choice.

Comment: I think the canonical answer is that **it depends**. It might be more instructive for you to ask "When should I use one or the other". As @Dummy commented, the you're asking "pure function vs impure" - I suggest googling for that